# 'cookbook' is missing in the structure of knife solo init

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When i type `knife solo init .` command, `cookbook` folder is not created in the basic structure.
I cannot find any reason why it is doing this.
my chef and knife are the latest version so far.
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the code here: https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/blob/v0.5.1/lib/chef/knife/solo_init.rb#L35

The only thing that would prevent it from making the `cookbooks/` folder is if a file of the same name exists.

Comment: The code is all there, you can draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Maybe it's because i did something wrong! anyway, thank you for replying!